# How to loop over exact representations of floating point numbers?

Tags: c++, loops, ieee-754

I am trying to loop exactly from one floating point number to the next. Say, I need to loop from `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` to `1`, which are both exactly representable IEEE754 numbers. My code is:

```
 using nld = std::numeric_limits<float>;
 auto h = nld::epsilon();
 for (; h < 1; h = std::nextafter(h, 1)) {
     std::cerr << "h: " << h << std::endl;
 }
```

which loops indefinitely beacuse h is exactly representable, so `nextafter` keeps returning it. I also know that adding machine epsilon to h in a loop will not cut it: floating point numbers are not equally spaced. How do I loop over the exact representations of IEEE754 numbers?

The `not equally spaced` problem presents itself here:

```
 using nld = std::numeric_limits<float>;
 auto h = nld::epsilon();
 for (; h < 4; h += nld::epsilon()) {
     if (h = h + nld::epsilon()) {
         std::cerr << "h: " << h << std::endl;
     }
 }
```

which keeps printing `2` for me

Comment: `nextafter` is exactly what you should be doing. I cannot understand your comment that h is exactly representable. Of course *any* floating-point number stored in a variable is exactly representable. Does your system perhaps lack the `float` overload of `nextafter`, meaning you get the `double` implementation, which may return values that *cannot* be represented in `float`? If so, you could try `nextafterf`.

Comment: @hvd nextafter(h, 1) keeps returning `h` for me. I will try to force it to `nextafterf`

Comment: @hvd oh, you are correct, when forced to work with floats, `nextafterf` (note the f) does loop over the floating point numbers. Turns out, my `nextafter` was indeed `double`, thank you!

Comment: Oh wait... Your second argument `1` has type `int`, and *that* forces the use of the `double` overload. You'd need `1.0f` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments:

The approach with `nextafter` is exactly what you should be doing. However, it has some complications that may lead to unexpected results.

Quoting cppreference [`std::nextafter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/nextafter):

> `float       nextafter( float from, float to );` (1)  (since C++11)
>   `double      nextafter( double from, double to );` (2)    (since C++11)
>   `long double nextafter( long double from, long double to );` (3)  (since C++11)
>   `Promoted    nextafter( Arithmetic from, Arithmetic to );` (4)    (since C++11)
>
> ...
>
> 4) A set of overloads or a function template for all combinations of arguments of arithmetic type not covered by (1-3). If any argument has integral type, it is cast to `double`. If any argument is `long double`, then the return type `Promoted` is also `long double`, otherwise the return type is always `double`.

Since your `to` is `1`, of type `int`, you get overload version 4, with a return type of `double`. Now, it's entirely possible that given a float `f`, `(float)nextafter((double)f, 1)` is exactly equal to the original `f`: it's rather likely that the next representable number in type `double` cannot be represented in `float`, and that the conversion back to `float` rounds down.

The only overload that returns `float` is the one where `to` has type `float`. To use that overload, use `1.0f` instead of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

treating them as integers will work for notmal positive floats, 
negative floats will step in the wrong direction, and denormals and zero may be a special case.

eg: for positive normal floats:

```
float nextfloat(float in)
{   
   union { float f; uint32_t i; } a;
   a.f=in;
   a.i++;
   return(a.f);
}
```

this is relies on the floats having the same endianness and size as the integers, here I pair float and uint32_t, but you could do the same for double and uint64_t... this could actually be a class of undefined behavior,  testing its operation should probably be poart of the build process.

Comment: @hvd if he's starting at epsilon that's a normal float, so he'll get coverage and monotonicity all the way to 1

Comment: Oh, reading more accurately, I see you did list most of the assumptions you've made in your answer, both on implementations and on what your code can be used for, and your code does work as long as your assumptions hold. I don't think it's a good general solution, but it's actually surprisingly close on typical implementations.